# How to compute the variance of very small numerical values?

Tags: python, precision, underflow

Today, I heard of the term [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) and would like to know what is the right way to compute the variance of very small numerical values in general? Since I use Python very often, I am mainly interested in whether Numpy's `numpy.var()` implementation takes catastrophic cancellation into account? What can I do if that is not the case?

Comment: Try this Wikipedia formula (along with its example Python code): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Computing_shifted_data

Comment: @minterm Does that mean I just do `numpy.var(x-x.mean())` to avoid catastrophic cancellation?

Comment: Yes assuming the mean function is accurate. Also, from the Numpy documentation, specify the data type as np.float64 for maximum precision. See the last example in the documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.var.html?highlight=var#numpy.var